# SQL Query return unique result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a scenario as shown below:

The Project Manager(pm) or Delivery manager(dm) should be able to view records assigned to him.

1. The Sow and Child_Sow contains project_Id and User_id both primary keys.
2. The Project table contains project_id_sys which is not primary key.

The result I want is unique records for sow and child_sow which contains project_id_sys as some list of values.

Is it possible? Maybe the design of the tables is faulty or incomplete. Currently, the returned results shows many rows instead of basic rows who he/she is eligible.

Sow Table

```
sow_id
project_id (fk to project_id)
sow_desc
```

Child_Sow Table

```
child_sow_id
project_id (fk to project_id)
child_sow_desc
```

project table

```
project_id
project_id_sys
pm
dm
```

User Table

```
User_id
User_id_sys
```

My current query is:

```
select sow.project_id,child_sow.project_id,project.project_id 
from project
inner join sow
on sow.project_id = project.project_id
join child_sow
on child_sow.project_id = project.project_id
where project.project_id_sys IN( 4001);
```

Comment: Your post is a little chaotic. Have you heard of `DISTINCT`? Is it helpful for your case? If not, can you provide expected output?

Comment: @MrAjay so, do you want the data where both `sow` and `child_sow` both have records with `project_id_sys` or do you want the data if `project_id_sys` is in one but not the other?